Extends or Mixins in Sass?
I use scss in my application. I use these rules quite often.
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;

I want to reuse these styles with mixins or extends. I want to understand what is the best way.
On one hand, using Mixins is more safe, but on the other, it generates more CSS in the output. Extends along with placeholders generates less CSS in the output, but can cause cascade problems. What is the best case for this set of rules.
// Mixins
@mixin flex-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

// Somewhere in the component's styles
.title {
  @include flex-center;
}

// Extends
%flex-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

// Somewhere in the component's styles
.title {
  @extend %flex-center;
}


I think there are different ways of doing this as you mentioned. Extending, mixins, etc. But if its a simple use case like centering a div, then maybe also consider, adding a class in global styles and simply re-using it?? That should not hurt more I think. I am assuming you are using angular as your framework here. But if that is not the case, and you have to use either mixins / extending, I would recommend going with mixins as you rightly mentioned, it will not cause cascading issues.
